# Invoke jQuery from action form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

From a HTML form, I invoke a jQuery method, triggering an alert message and make an image become visible, but the image disappears  after a second? This is my form:

```
<form action= "jquery.php" method="post" > 
    <label for="farfar">Farfar:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="farfar" name="farfar"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Tilføj">
</form>
```

In the file `jquery.php`, I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
        $(".ff").show();
    });
});
```

And I have made a PHP script:

```
<?php
    $farfar = $_POST['farfar'];
?>
```

The image is a class (outside the script):

```
img class ="ff" src="human.png"...
```

In my CSS file, I have set the current value on images.

```
img {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now, when I load the page and give the form a value, the jQuery is properly invoked, the alert message is shown and the image shows. But only for 1 second or so, then it disappears again. What am I doing wrong? and how can I make the image stay on the screen?

Comment: After submitting form, you lost everything. you need to use `ajax` for submitting form, if you want to keep page state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your image disappears is that your page POSTs and that changes the content of the page. I am not sure which URL you're POSTing your for to but you could try POSTing the form to self, then might work. Or you could also use jQuery to POST the form via async so the page does not load.